# Ogr2Ogr exporting PostGis => GeoJson

Tags: postgis, geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm exporting from PostGis to GeoJson, but appear to have no control over the table it retrieves. Have tried the following methods:

> .\ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "C:\Temp\output.geojson" "PG:host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" -sql "SELECT * FROM with_id"

- SELECT from table with_id failed, no such table/featureclass.

> .\ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "C:\Temp\output.geojson" "PG:host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" -sql "SELECT * FROM public.with_id"

- Unable to open secondary datasource `public' required by JOIN.

> .\ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "C:\Temp\output.geojson" "PG:host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" with_id

- Couldn't fetch requested layer 'with_id'!

> .\ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "C:\Temp\output.geojson" "PG:host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" public.with_id

- Couldn't fetch requested layer 'public.with_id'!

Comment: try excluding `PG:` from the quotes.

Comment: Does ogrinfo list the table "with_id" if you run  `"ogrinfo PG:host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply don't have a table called `public.with_id`.

Try dumping it regularly with `pg_dump`. My guess is you're connected to the wrong database.

Comment: Looks like Ogr2Ogr is clever, and removes _. There I go making assumptions again.